# How do I test if an object is inside another one using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Without using plug-ins, how would I check if an element is inside another? I tried using
`element.hover();`
but to no avail. Is this possible with pure JQuery, or should I look for a workaround?

The code currently looks like

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".element_to_drag").mousedown(function(){  
    $(this).addClass("dragging");   
    $(".dragging").live("mousemove", function(e) {  
        var offset = $("#container").offset();  
        var x = offset.left;  
        var y = offset.top;  
        $(this).css("position", "absolute");  
        $(this).css("left", e.pageX - x);  
        $(this).css("top", e.pageY - y);  
    })  
    $(".dragging").live("mouseup", function(e)  
    {  
        $(this).removeClass("dragging");  
    })  
    $("#elementContainer").hover(function()  
        {  
            $(".dragging").css("background-color", "red");  
        });  
    });  
});
```

I'm very much still learning, feel free to critique anything.

Comment: Are you talking about if an element is further down the DOM tree than another element, or if when dragging an element around, the coordinates of the dragging element are inside another element?  If the former, `closest()` might work.  If the latter, I believe jQueryUI (which you're likely using for the dragging) can give you information about droppable() items.  Also, the css() function uses Javascript equivalents to CSS properties, ie: backgroundColor, not background-color.

Comment: I should have clarified, I mean I want to check if the co-ordinates of the dragged element are inside of the container, at which point I'd like to have more executable code. Jquery UI is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Update your mousemove function to contain this instead:

```
$(this).css("position", "absolute");  
$(this).css("left", e.pageX - $(this).width()/2);  
$(this).css("top", e.pageY - $(this).height()/2);
```

`$(this)` refers to your draggable object. Then all you need to do to see if the draggable object is contained inside the `#container` is if an if statement that checks if $(this).css("left") is greater than the X position (not offset: see http://api.jquery.com/position/) of the container.

Of course you might want to do some checks as well to look at the width of the draggable item and ensure that it sits entirely inside the container.